# A sequence of random variables converge in distribution to some random variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a sequence of i.i.d $Uniform[0,1]$ random variables, $X_1, X_2,...$. By taking logs find a random variable $X$ such that $(X_1...X_n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}e^{\sqrt{n}} \to X$ in distribution.

I approached this by trying to find the cdf:
$\mathbb{P}((X_1...X_n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}e^{\sqrt{n}} < x) = \mathbb{P}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\log X_1 + ... + \log X_n) + \sqrt{n} < \log x)$

And then using the fact that $\log X_i$ ~ $Exp(1)$ and the sum of n exponential variables is a $Gamma(n,1)$ variable. But I now can't really see how this makes the probability any simpler by actually using these facts.

Comment: This is a central limit theorem problem.  Try using the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\log(X_1) + \cdots + \log(X_n)) + \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(\log(X_1e) + \cdots + \log(X_n e))$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

So using this and that $\mathbb{E}(\log X_i) = -\frac{1}{2}$, $Var(\log X_i) = \frac{3}{16}$ we can get $\mathbb{E}(\log e X_i) = \frac{1}{2}$, $Var(\log e X_i) = \frac{3}{16}$, and so by Central Limit Theorem this converges to a $Normal(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{16})$ variable?

Comment: My calculation is that $E[\log(X_1)]=-1$.

Comment: Also recall that CLT requires a sum of zero-mean terms.  If $\{Y_1,Y_2, \ldots\}$ are i.i.d. with finite mean $E[Y]$ and finite variance $Var(Y)$ then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-E[Y])$ converges in distribution to a Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $Var(Y)$.  In contrast, if $E[Y]>0$ then by LLN $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i = \sqrt{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i \approx \sqrt{n}E[Y]\rightarrow\infty$ (with prob 1).  Formally, with prob 1 for all sufficiently large $n$ we get $\sqrt{n}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i \geq \sqrt{n}E[Y]/2\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+log%28x%29%2C+x%3D0..1

Comment: For U~UNIF(0,1), it's  -log(U) that's exponential.